# returning Class from server to client in DART lang

Tags: postgresql, dart

I've this server code using postgresql  pub available [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql)

```
class Vendor {
   String name;
   String email;
}

void gVendors(HttpRequest req){
    HttpResponse res = req.response;
   addCorsHeaders(res);
   print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');

   req.listen((List<int> buffer) {

   connect(db).then((conn) {
   conn.query('select * from VNDRS')
   .map((row) => new Vendor()
                            ..name = row.vname
                            ..email = row.email)
   .toList()
       .then((List<Vendor> vendors) {
           for (var c in vendors) {
               print(c is Vendor);    // this is correct
               print(c.name);         // this is correct
               print(c.email);        // this is correct
           }
       })
       .then((_){
           res.write(Vendor);      // ??
           res.close();
          });
    }); 
  }, onError: printError);
}
```

when I checked in the client, and printed

```
print(request.responseText);
```

the output was the word "Vendor"

can I send the Class from the vendor to client, or is there another way to send the output of my sql here to the client.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I want using the following code, but still interested to know/learn how to get it as Class

```
void gVendors(HttpRequest req){

 HttpResponse res = req.response;
 addCorsHeaders(res);
 print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');

 Future future() => new Future.value(true);
 var db = 'postgres://postgres:pswd@localhost:5432/postgres';

 req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
  //var _theData = JSON.decode(new String.fromCharCodes(buffer));

 var vndrs = <Map>[];
    connect(db).then((conn) {
       conn.query('select * from VNDRS')
       .toList().then((rows) {         
         future()
           .then((_){
                  for (var row in rows)
                      vndrs.add({
                          'name':row.vndrnum,
                           'num':row.vname,
                         'email':row.email
                        });
                  })
           .then((_)=>res.write(JSON.encode(vndrs)))
           .then((_)=>res.close()); 
         }); 
     });  
  }, onError: printError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you need to send to the client is the list of vendor objects, which was built from the database result, not the vendor class.

Also, you can't write a object directly to the response, you need to serialize it. For example, you can use the `JSON` codec, from the `dart:convert` library, to serialize objects to JSON:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:conver';

class Vendor {

  String name;
  String email;

  Vendor([this.name, this.email]);

  Vendor.fromJson(Map json) {
    name = json["name"];
    email = json["email"];
  }

  Map toJson() => {"name": name, "email": email};
}

void gVendors(HttpRequest req){
  HttpResponse res = req.response;
  addCorsHeaders(res);
  print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');

  req.listen((List<int> buffer) {

  connect(db).then((conn) {
    conn.query('select * from VNDRS')
    .map((row) => new Vendor(row.vname, row.email));
    .toList()
     .then((List<Vendor> vendors) {
         for (var c in vendors) {
             print(c is Vendor);    // this is correct
             print(c.name);         // this is correct
             print(c.email);        // this is correct
         }

         res.write(JSON.encode(vendors.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList()));
         res.headers.set("content-type", "application/json");
         res.close();
     }); 
  }, onError: printError);
}
```

In this example, the Vendor class has methods that translate from and to JSON. In the client side, you can also use these methods to parse the response:

```
var vendors = JSON.decode(request.response).map((o) => new Vendor.fromJson(o));
```

If you don't want to write these methods for every serializable class, you can look for a  library that does this job for you, such as [redstone_mapper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redstone_mapper).

Comment: I got this error in the server side "Uncaught Error: HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable", and if I removed the "res.headers.contentType= new ContentType('application','JSON');" then I get the below output printed in the browser console, wihout having a print statement to call it from the client code.. [{"name":"Vendor 1","email":"v1@gmail.com"},{"name":"Vendor 2","email":"v2@gmail.com"}]
[{VNDRNUM: null, VNAME: null, EMAIL: null}, {VNDRNUM: null, VNAME: null, EMAIL: null}]

Comment: At .map((row)=>new Vendor(). It gives an error of class does not have a default constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code so the `content-type` header is added with the `response.headers.set()` method. Also, I've added a default constructor to Vendor, so you can use it to parse the database result. I hope that helps.

Comment: I got this error in the server: Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable